# how to insert newline in python xml.etree module

Tags: python, xml, escaping, newline

I want to print out the xml like this:

```
<xml>
    <tag>
        this is line 1.
        this is line 2.
    </tag>
</xml>
```

I have a piece of code like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
xml = ET.Element('xml')
tag = ET.SubElement(xml, 'tag')
tag.text = 'this is line 1.' + '&#x000A;' + 'this is line 2.'
tree = ET.ElementTree(xml)
tree.write('test.xml')
```

But it print out like this:

```
<xml>
    <tag>this is line 1.&#x000A;this is line 2.</tag>
</xml>
```

When I use `'\n'` instead of `'&#x000A;'`, the output is like this:

```
<xml>
    <tag>this is line 1. this is line 2.</tag>
</xml>
```

How can I insert a `newline` between 'this is line 1.' and 'this is line 2.'

Comment: Why are you trying to use a XML escape code instead of a regular newline character?

Comment: @MartijnPieters because `\n` doesn't work at all.

Comment: it does for me. How are you verifying that it doesn't work?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have post my output with '\n'.

Comment: I know, I saw that. But I cannot reproduce that output.

Comment: I can't reproduce getting the text in one line using '\n', perhaps you could post the exact code you're using?

Comment: @HennyH I'm using exactly the same code as you posted. And my web browser is chrome.

Comment: I opened it in internet explorer 10 and see it as one line as you've said. Try open it in notepad and it will be separated. I can't explain why this happens though my guess would be it's simply the browser trying to format it. If you right click and select 'view source' or equivalent it displays it separated (in IE10).

Comment: Your web browser can choose to format whitespace *differently*. It doesn't have to show you newlines. What does `print ET.tostring(tree.getroot())` show you?

Comment: @HennyH You are right. The 'view source' tool print out them in two lines. Chrome has wasted me a lot of time. Thanks again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `print ET.tostring(tree.getroot())` print them in two separate lines. So I did not see the newline because of chrome.

Comment: hi @MartijnPieters what web browser do you use to display xml properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use '\n' to make a newline I.e

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
xml = ET.Element('xml')
tag = ET.SubElement(xml, 'tag')
tag.text = 'this is line 1.' + '\n' + 'this is line 2.'
tree = ET.ElementTree(xml)
tree.write('test.xml')
```

Will produce

```
<xml><tag>this is line 1.
this is line 2.</tag></xml>
```

This is equivalent to

```
<xml>
    <tag>
        this is line 1.
        this is line 2.
    </tag>
</xml>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. 'this is line 1.' and 'this is line 2.' are still in the same line.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you unable to produce the output I said the code above would output?

Comment: Not the same with yours. The two lines are in the same line in my output.

Comment: I have post my output in my post.

Comment: hi HennyH, what web browser do you use to display xml properly?

Comment: IE10 and Chrome were the browsers I tested it on.